# Total Variation Distance and Number of Samples

Tags: probability-distributions, total-variation

I don't know a distribution $P_{XY}$. However, I can randomly get some samples (X,Y) from this distribution. Based on $n$ samples, I approximated the distribution as $P'_{XY}$. How can I bound the total variation distance between $P_{XY}$ and $P'_{XY}$?

Comment: Do you assume that $P_{XY}$ is discrete? Otherwise, the total variation distance is just $1$.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Yes, $P_{XY}$ is discrete

Comment: This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.6711.pdf) may be useful.